# HTML formatted email using netcat bash shell script

Tags: bash, colors, html-email, netcat

how to send html format with color text emil with netcat i don't need send mail method just want to using netcat and how to add the head properly i create a script to send mail with color text ,this script send only the email with html tags not with color can you point out what i,m doing wrong here

```
function mail_input {
  echo "ehlo $(hostname -f)"
  echo "MAIL FROM: <$from>"
  echo "RCPT TO: <$to>"
 # echo "RCPT TO: <$to1>"
  #echo "RCPT TO: <$to2>"
  #echo "RCPT TO: <$to3>"
 # echo "RCPT TO: <$to4>"
  echo "DATA"
  echo "From: <$from>"
  echo "To: <$to>"
  #echo "cc: <$to1>"
  #echo "cc: <$to2>"
  #echo "cc: <$to3>"
 # echo "cc: <$to4>"
  echo "Subject: $subject"
  echo ""
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r"
echo `Content-type: text/html`

  echo "Dear All,"
  echo ""

        echo "<html><b><font size='7'>H</font>ello</b></html>"
         echo "<font color=\"red\"> mandate count first re try  $revenue </font> " 
  echo ""
  echo "."
  echo "quit"
}

mail_input | /usr/bin/nc $mail_server $port || err_exit
```

Comment: if you cant give a answer it's ok but  don't down grade this .if you are down grades this just give me a reason for that

Answer (score 0):

1. You've embedded the `html` tag inside plain text, which is definitely going to mess with user agents.
2. You've terminated the `html` tag *before* the end of the email.
3. There's no `body` tag.

A minimal HTML document looks something like this (it depends on the version of HTML and whether the user agent can handle some stuff being missing):

```
<html><body>[all user visible markup goes here]</body></html>
```